# Unexpected message - no endpoint registered with connection interceptor while communicating with multiple servers

Tags: spring, sockets, spring-integration, tcplistener

```
    @Configuration
@Component
public class GatewayAqrConfig {

    @Autowired
    ConnectorService connectorService;

    @Autowired
    MasterService masterService;

    private HashMap<ConnectorPK, GatewayAqr> connectorMap;

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientCF(Connector connector , Master master) {
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(connector.getAqrIpAddr(), connector.getAqrIpPortNo());
        clientConnectionFactory.setSingleUse(false);        
        MyByteArraySerializer obj = new MyByteArraySerializer(master.getAqrMsgHeaderLength(), master.getAqrId());
        clientConnectionFactory.setSerializer(obj);
        clientConnectionFactory.setDeserializer(obj);       
        clientConnectionFactory.setSoKeepAlive(true);
        TcpMessageMapper tcpMessageMapper = new TcpMessageMapper();
        tcpMessageMapper.setCharset("ISO-8859-1");
        clientConnectionFactory.setMapper(tcpMessageMapper);        
        clientConnectionFactory.setBeanName(connector.getAqrIpAddr() + ":" + connector.getAqrIpPortNo());               
        clientConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        clientConnectionFactory.start();        
        return clientConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpOutGateway(AbstractClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {      
        TcpSendingMessageHandler messageHandler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        messageHandler.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);     
        messageHandler.setClientMode(true);
        messageHandler.setTaskScheduler(getTaskScheduler());
        messageHandler.setStatsEnabled(true);
        messageHandler.afterPropertiesSet();
        messageHandler.start();     
        return messageHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter tcpInGateway(AbstractClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter messageHandler = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        messageHandler.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);             
        messageHandler.setClientMode(true);
        messageHandler.setOutputChannel(receive());
        messageHandler.setAutoStartup(true);
        messageHandler.setTaskScheduler(getTaskScheduler());
        messageHandler.afterPropertiesSet();
        messageHandler.start();
        return messageHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public TaskScheduler getTaskScheduler() {
        TaskScheduler ts = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        return ts;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel receive() {
        QueueChannel channel = new QueueChannel();      
        return channel;
    }

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata poller() { 
        return new PollerMetadata();
    }

    @Bean
    @Transactional
    public HashMap<ConnectorPK, GatewayAqr> gatewayAqr() throws Exception {
        connectorMap = new HashMap();
        Connector connector = null;
        ConnectorPK connectorPK = null;
        Master master = null;
        TcpConnectionSupport connectionSupport = null;

        // 1. Get List of Connections configured in Database
        List<Connector> connectors = connectorService.getConnections();

        if (connectors.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < connectors.size(); i++) {

                // 2. Get the connection details
                connector = connectors.get(i);
                connectorPK = aqrConnector.getConnectorpk();
                master = masterService.findById(connectorPK.getAcuirerId());                

                try {
                    // 3. Create object of TcpNetClientConnectionFactory for each Acquirer connection
                    AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory = clientCF(aqrConnector, aqrMaster);                    

                    // 4. Create TcpSendingMessageHandler for the Connection
                    TcpSendingMessageHandler outHandler = tcpOutGateway(clientConnectionFactory);                   

                    // 5. Create TcpReceivingChannelAdapter object for the Connection and assign it to receive channel
                    TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inHandler = tcpInGateway(clientConnectionFactory);

                    // 6. Generate the GatewayAqr object
                    GatewayAqr gatewayAqr = new GatewayAqr(clientConnectionFactory, outHandler, inHandler);

                    // 7. Put in the MAP acuirerPK and Send MessageHandler object
                    connectorMap.put(aqrConnectorPK, gatewayAquirer);                   
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            } // for
        } // if
        return connectorMap;
    }
}

*********************************************************************************************************************************
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {GatewayEventConfig.class,GatewayAqrConfig.class })
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.iz.zw.gateway.impl", "com.iz.zw.configuration"})
@Import({GatewayEventConfig.class,GatewayAquirerConfig.class})
public class GatewayConfig {

    @Autowired
    private GatewayAsyncReply<Object, Message<?>> gatewayAsyncReply;

    @Autowired
    private GatewayCorrelationStrategy gatewayCorrelationStrategy;

    @Autowired
    private HashMap<ConnectorPK, GatewayAqr> gatewayAqrs;

    @Autowired
    ConnectorService connectorService;

    @Autowired
    GatewayResponseDeserializer gatewayResponseDeserializer;    

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "send")
    public interface Gateway {
        void waitForResponse(TransactionMessage transaction);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel send() {
        DirectChannel channel = new DirectChannel();        
        return channel;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "send")
    public BarrierMessageHandlerWithLateGoodResponse barrier() {
        BarrierMessageHandlerWithLateGoodResponse barrier = new BarrierMessageHandlerWithLateGoodResponse(25000, this.gatewayCorrelationStrategy);      
        barrier.setAsync(true);
        barrier.setOutputChannel(out());
        barrier.setDiscardChannel(lateGoodresponseChannel());
        return barrier;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "out")
    public void printMessage(Message<?> message) {
        System.out.println("in out channel");
    }

    @Transformer(inputChannel = "receive", outputChannel = "process")
    public TransactionMessage convert(byte[] response) {    

        logger.debug("Response Received", Arrays.toString(response));
        TransactionMessage transactionMessage = gatewayResponseDeserializer.deserializeResponse(response);      
        System.out.println("Response : " + response);       
        return transactionMessage;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "process")
    @Bean
    public MessageHandler releaser() {
        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                try {               
                    gatewayAsyncReply.put(message);             
                    barrier().trigger(message);
                } catch (GatewayLateGoodMessageException exception) {                   
                    System.out.println("Late good response..!");
                    gatewayAsyncReply.get(message);
                    lateGoodresponseChannel().send(message);
                }                               
            }
        };
    }   

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel process() {   
        QueueChannel channel = new QueueChannel();
        return channel;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel out() {
        DirectChannel channel = new DirectChannel();        
        return channel;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel lateGoodresponseChannel() {
        QueueChannel channel = new QueueChannel();
        return channel;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="lateGoodresponseChannel")
    public void handleLateGoodResponse(Message<?> message) {
        String strSTAN = null;
        String strResponse = null;
        Message<?> respMessage = null;

        if(message instanceof TransactionMessage){
            strSTAN = ((TransactionMessage)message).getStan();
            respMessage = gatewayAsyncReply.get(strSTAN);

            if (null != respMessage) {              
                strResponse = (String) message.getPayload();                
            }
        }               
        logger.info("Late Good Response: " + strResponse);      
    }
}

*********************************************************************************************************************************

@Configuration
public class GatewayEventConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GatewayEventConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer tcpEventListener() {
        ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer producer = new ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer();
        producer.setEventTypes(new Class[] {TcpConnectionOpenEvent.class, TcpConnectionCloseEvent.class, TcpConnectionExceptionEvent.class});
        producer.setOutputChannel(tcpEventChannel());
        producer.setAutoStartup(true);
        producer.setTaskScheduler(getEventTaskScheduler());
        producer.start();
        return producer;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler getEventTaskScheduler() {
        TaskScheduler ts = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        return ts;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel tcpEventChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Transactional
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "tcpEventChannel")
    public void tcpConnectionEvent(TcpConnectionEvent event) {

        System.out.println("In publishing" + event.toString());
        String strConnectionFactory = event.getConnectionFactoryName();

        if (strConnectionFactory.equals("connection1")) {            
                //send some message to connector            
        } else {
            // send message to another connector
        }
    }
}
```

this is my configuration files, my application tries to connect to 2 servers as soon as it starts.
I have made 2 configurations for 2 servers as above class
    **GatewayAqrConfig1 and GatewayConfig1 classes are used for first server connection**
    **GatewayAqrConfig2 and GatewayConfig2 classes are used for second server connection**
Using event I am connecting to server and sending a connection set up message, if server is already started and If I have started my application, 
    **it gets the event, connects and sends the message but I am not getting the response** instead I am getting the WARNING as below

```
**WARN  TcpNetConnection:186 - Unexpected message - no endpoint registered with connection interceptor:**
    i.e connection does not registers the listener properly
```

but if I am starting my application first and then servers I am getting responses perfectly, As I am connecting to servers 
I could not restart it ? My application should connect to server which is already started ? what could be the problem ?

Version used:

Spring integration Version : 4.3.1

Spring version : 4.3.2

JDK 1.8 on JBOSS EAP 7

Comment: I haven't looked at your code closely, but your can't use `prototype` scope for Spring Integration beans.

Comment: is there anything I am missing or any mistake apart from scope ? will you have check it ? it will be very helpful..!

Comment: You need to remove the scope and come back if you are still having problems; edit the question with the current configuration and errors.

Comment: I have removed scope values and checked it and the result is same but when I set the setClientMode(false) for TcpSendingMessageHandler, it's working fine, what was the issue ? can you explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That WARN message means that, somehow, an inbound message was received without a `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` having been registered with the connection factory. Client mode should make no difference.

Having looked at your code a little more, the prototype beans should be ok, as long as you use those objects (especially `TcpMessageHandler` directly rather than via the framework).

It's not obvious to me how that can happen, given your configuration; the listener is registered when you call `setConnectionFactory` on the receiving adapter.

If you can reproduce it with a trimmed-down project and post it someplace, I will take a look.